# C - Dereferencing void pointer

Tags: c

I'm trying to create my own swap function but I have troubles. 
Why I'm getting " dereferencing void pointer " ?

```
void    ft_swap(void *a, void *b, size_t nbytes)
{
    unsigned char   *cur_a;
    unsigned char   *cur_b;
    size_t          i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < nbytes)
    {
        cur_a = (unsigned char *)*a + i; // here
        cur_b = (unsigned char *)*b + i; // here

        *a = cur_b;
        *b = cur_a;

        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: usually, that is a compiler warning with a line number pointing to exactly the line where that happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not allowed to dereference void pointer. You need to cast it to another pointer type:

```
cur_a = (unsigned char *)a;
```

Similarly, you can't assign anything to `*a`. Right code is:

```
void ft_swap(void *a, void *b, size_t nbytes) {
    unsigned char  *cur_a = (unsigned char *) a;
    unsigned char  *cur_b = (unsigned char *) b;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nbytes; ++i) {
        unsigned char tmp = cur_a[i];
        cur_a[i] = cur_b[i];
        cur_b[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or, better, use a `for` loop so the loop control is all on a single line.  In C99 or C11, you can use `for (size_t i = 0; i < nbytes; i++)`, declaring the variable on the loop control line too.  I'd probably define `tmp` inside the loop too — but that's a very minor change.

Answer (score 2):

You want to cast the (abstract) `void*` pointer to a pointer to  `unsigned char` so code:

```
cur_a = (unsigned char *)a + i;
```

Your code was understood as `cur_a = (unsigned char *)(*a) + i;` which wrongly dereferences a `void*` abstract pointer.

BTW, your `*a = cur_b;` does not make sense neither. Perhaps you want

```
((unsigned char*)a)[i] = cur_b;
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are dereferencing void pointers:

```
void    ft_swap(void *a, void *b, size_t nbytes)
{
 ...
        cur_a = (unsigned char *)*a + i; // here
        cur_b = (unsigned char *)*b + i; // here
```

Doing `*a` means you first dereference `a`, and then you cast the result (whatever that is, dereferencing `void*` doesn't make much sense) to a pointer to `unsigned char`. Doing

```
cur_a = *((unsigned char *)a) + i;
```

makes more sense.

Comment: Except unary `*` has higher priority than `+`. Correct code would be `cur_a = *((unsigned char *)a + i);` which is same as `((unsigned char*)a)[i]` but somewhat less readable.

Comment: That depends. I assumed OP wanted to add the numeric value i to the uint8 at a.

Answer (score 0):

```
    cur_a = (unsigned char *)*a + i; // here
                             ^^^ that is dereferencing a void*

    cur_b = (unsigned char *)*b + i; // here
                             ^^^ that is dereferencing a void* also.
```

In the lines:

```
    *a = cur_b;
    *b = cur_a;
```

you are dereferencing `void*` too.

Here's my suggestion to fix the function:

```
void ft_swap(void *a, void *b, size_t nbytes)
{
   unsigned char* cpa;
   unsigned char* cpb;
   size_t          i;
   unsigned char c;

   cpa = (unsigned char *)a;
   cpb = (unsigned char *)b;

   for ( i = 0; i < nbytes; ++i )
   {
      c = cpa[i];
      cpa[i] = cpb[i];
      cpb[i] = c;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look your statement

```
cur_a = (unsigned char *)*a + i; // here
```

if `a` is a pointer to void (`void *a`) then `*a = void`. Then the subexpression `(unsigned char *)*a` means that you want to cast `void` to a pointer to char.

But `void` means **'inexistent type'** in C, from this the error.
You may ask why a pointer to void make sense instead, it makes sense because it is an address, that is a valid data type in C. You can use the address for all the operations that doesn't involve the pointed type. I.e. assigning the address to a pointer to whichever type of data, and the reverse, is legal. It's is illegal an expression like `a[2]` where the subscript operator `[]` need the size of the data pointed to compute the address where to retrieve the value. Of course `void`, as bogus type, have no size (same way as it miss many other properties).

Said that I would conclude that it was just an error in your code, and that what you really want to do is:

```
void    ft_swap(void *a, void *b, size_t nbytes)
{
    unsigned char   cur_a;    //value not pointers
    unsigned char   cur_b;
    size_t          i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < nbytes)
    {
        cur_a = *((unsigned char *)a + i); // here
        cur_b = *((unsigned char *)b + i); // here

        *a = cur_b;
        *b = cur_a;

        i++;
    }
}
```