# What kind of role does the pointer to void play in the following declaration?

Tags: c

In the book The C Programming Language(K&R2) Chapter 5, the author gives a general-purpose sorting routine with the following declaration.

```
void qsort(void *lineptr[], int left, int right, int (*comp)(void *, void *));
```

What kind of role does the pointer to void play in this declaration? Is it common to use pointer to void in C programs in this way? What is the advantage or disadvantage of this kind of code?

Comment: Sorry, too broad.

Comment: Which other type of pointer would you use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the book you referenced:

> As indicated  by the function  prototype, `qsort` expects an array  of pointers, two integers, and a function with two pointer arguments.  The generic pointer type `void*` is used for the pointer arguments.  Any pointer can be cast to `void*` and back again without loss of information,  so we can call `qsort` by casting arguments  to `void*`

Since `void*` is used in the function prototype, you can use `qsort` to sort data of any type (`int`, `double`, `char*`, `struct`, etc.). All you have to do is provide a callback function that casts the void pointers to pointers of the correct type before dereferencing them and performing the comparison.

The use of a function that accepts different data types avoids [unnecessary repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) in your code, which is always a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer to void is usefull when you provide a function and don't want to limit the user of the function with a parameter type.
More generally, the void pointer is used when you don't know which type of pointer you are manipulating.

Is this example the function *qsort* will sort lines, but the function don't know the type of the line. So it lets you using the function with any type of lines using a void pointers array. The function *qsort* will call the fonction *comp* passed in parameters with the lines of the array. Here again the *comp* function take void pointers parameters, allowing you to create a comparison function which take any type of parameters.

Comment: should be added that `void*` are different from other pointers because they can't be dereferenced and must be casted back to there original type to be used

Comment: Pointers of different types may have different representations. This is implementation-dependent.

Comment: This could be a good answer if you fixed the factual error (probably by simply deleting the second paragraph).

Comment: As your wish. It was not really wrong but I understand why you don't like it.

Comment: @TimothéeFicat Well not exactly. From the ANSI C standard ([ISO/IEC 9899:199 ¶6.2.5.26](http://www.dii.uchile.cl/~daespino/files/Iso_C_1999_definition.pdf)): *A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type. {...} Pointers to other types **need not have the same representation** or alignment requirements.* Anyway, welcome to SO, and have an upvote from me :)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Does the standard imply that the qsort routine may be wrong for `int, double, etc` because they may have different representation? Because I think different representation like different size may result in the situation that `lineptr[left]` refers to the wrong place.

Comment: @RiversShall No, not if the comparison callback function operates on the same data types as those of the array provided as the first argument provided to `qsort`. But in general, converting a pointer of one type to a pointer of another type (via `void *` or otherwise) will cause UB if the alignment requirements are incompatible. (See section 6.3.2.3 of the same document I linked to earlier.) So if you use `qsort` to sort an array of `double` values using a comparison routine that operates on `char *` pointers, then anything could happen.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage But if `sizeof(double)` is different from `sizeof(void *)`, then when we use `lineptr[left]` in the calling of comparison routine, it actually gives the address `lineptr + left * sizeof(void *)` instead of `lineptr + left * sizeof(double)` which is our intention. Under such circumstance, even if we use comparison routine that operates on `double`, the sorting will fail because the comparison routine gets the wrong address and thus, wrong object.

Comment: No, because the callback function will have to cast the `void *` pointer to the correct pointer type [before dereferencing it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32275889/1679849). For example, if you're sorting an array of `double` values, the `void *` pointers passed to the callback function will have to be converted to `double *` before the values they point to can be compared.