# ASM to C: how to dereference a pointer and add an offset?

Tags: c, pointers, assembly, x86-64, intel

I feel kind of dumb, but I'm struggling with dereferencing a pointer (+ adding an offset) in C.
What I want to recreate in C is this behavior:

```
movabs rax, 0xdeadbeef
add rax, 0xa
mov rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
```

So at the end rax should be: `*(0xdeadbeef+0xa)`
Especially the equivalent to `mov rax, QWORD PTR [rax]` would be improtant, as I need to use the calculated value and retrieve the data (=a different address) that is being stored at that point.

I tried so many things, but here is my current stage:

```
void *ptr = (void*)0xdeadbeef;
void *ptr2 = *(void*)(ptr+0xa);
```

Which translates to sth like this:

```
   0x7ffff7fe6050:      mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x38],rax
   0x7ffff7fe6054:      mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x38]
   0x7ffff7fe6058:      add    rax,0xa
```

*EDIT: It does not actually compile, I made a mistake with the provided C code here and can't figure out which code actually compiled to this. It's not that important anyways as the main target was the translation of ASM to C and the problem is solved now. Thanks everyone for participating.*

So the first 2 lines are basically useless and just the value is added to my address and nothing more. I need it to be interpreted as an address and retrieve the value at that point though.

The data stored at those places doesn't matter at this point. Essentially what I want to do is find a specific value in memory and I know a way of adding offsets and dereferencing pointers to get to my goal. The final step will just be a typecast from my address to the actual datatype at that point.

I know this may seem trivial to some of you, but I'm not super familiar with C, so I'm struggling here...

Comment: This is not possible because `void *ptr2 = *(void*)(ptr+0xa);` does not compile, so no code can possibly be generated.

Comment: There is a problem with your C code, you are computing a new pointer, then dereferencing it when it's a void*, ending up with a (bad) void type and assign it to a void*.

Comment: Why would you use 10-byte `movabs rax, 0xdeadbeef` instead of 5-byte `mov eax, 0xdeadbeef`?  Both set RAX to the same value.  And why not do it with a single instruction? `movabs rax, [0xdeadbeef + 0xa]` can use the AL/AX/EAX/RAX-only form of `mov` that loads from a 64-bit absolute address (http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html).  (It won't fit in a 32-bit sign-extended `disp32`, because the high bit of the low 32 is set, unlike normal static addresses in position-dependent code).  Regular `mov` with a 32-bit address-size override would work, too, in about 7 bytes.

Comment: @Jabberwocky and Matthieu Oh! I'm sorry, must have added the wrong C code - I tried so many casts and dereferences and brackets... I'll update the example, but my actual problem still stands.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I know, it is just an example. I know how to achieve it in ASM, but can't recreate it in C. I'll fix that expression, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointer arithmetic for void pointer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523145/pointer-arithmetic-for-void-pointer-in-c)

Comment: In C you can also do the whole thing with a single statement.  Like `void *ptr = *(void**)(0xdeadbeef + 0xa);`.  Except to avoid undefined behaviour from dereferencing a `void**` that's not aligned by 8 = `alignof(void*)`,  you'd want to use `memcpy`.

Comment: also : [C - Dereferencing void pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275765/c-dereferencing-void-pointer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify your asm to a single instruction, with the math done at assemble time.  `movabs rax, [0xdeadbeef + 0xa]` can use the AL/AX/EAX/RAX-only form of mov that loads from a 64-bit absolute address (https://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html). (It won't fit in a 32-bit sign-extended disp32, because the high bit of the low 32 is set, unlike normal static addresses in position-dependent code). Regular `mov` with a 32-bit address-size override would work, too, in about 7 bytes, because your address does fit in a zero-extended 32-bit integer.

**In C you can also do the whole thing with a single statement**.  No need to overcomplicate things: your address is a pointer *to* a pointer, so you need to cast your integer to a `x **` type.

```
void *ptr = *(const void**)(0xdeadbeefUL + 0xa);
```

In asm pointers are just integers, so it makes sense to do your math using integers instead of `char*`.  Making it unsigned guarantees it zero-extends to pointer-width instead of sign-extending.

(Numeric literals in C have a type wide enough to represent the value, though, so `0xdeadbeef` on an x86-64 compiler would be an `int64_t` (`long long`).  You wouldn't actually get `0xdeadbeef` being a negative 32-bit `int` that sign-extended to `0xffffffffdeadbeef`.)

Since `void` doesn't have a size, you can't add / subtract integers to a `void*`.  And pointer-math on `void **` would be in chunks of `sizeof(void*)`.

To avoid undefined behaviour from dereferencing a `void**` that's not aligned by `8 = alignof(void*)` (in both mainstream x86-64 ABIs), you'd want to use `memcpy`.  But I assume your example address is just a fake example.  The mainstream x86 compilers like gcc don't do anything weird with unaligned addresses to punish programmers for UB, so the compiler output will contain unaligned loads which work fine on x86.  But when auto-vectorizing you can run into problems from this kind of UB.  [Why does unaligned access to mmap'ed memory sometimes segfault on AMD64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510783/why-does-unaligned-access-to-mmaped-memory-sometimes-segfault-on-amd64)

---

But if you did for some reason want to break things up into multiple asm statements, **you could transliterate it into multiple C statements like this:**

```
uintptr_t wheres_the_beef = 0xdeadbeef;    // mov eax, 0xdeadbeef
wheres_the_beef += 0xa;                    // add eax, 0xa
void **address = (void**)wheres_the_beef;  // purely a cast, no asm instructions;
void *ptr = *address;                      // mov rax, [rax]
```

You could mess around with `char*` if you wanted to add byte offsets to pointers, but there's really no point here.

Again, this still has undefined behaviour on most C implementations, where `alignof(void*)` is greater than 1 so `void **address = (void**)wheres_the_beef` creates a misaligned pointer.

(Fun fact: even creating misaligned pointers is UB in ISO C.  But all x86 compilers that support Intel's intrinsics must support creating of misaligned pointers for passing them to intrinsics like `_mm_loadu_ps()`, so only actually dereferencing them is a potential problem on x86 compilers.)

Comment: I didn't think I'd ever write "where's the beef" in a stack overflow answer.  I crack myself up sometimes. :)

Comment: Wow, that was much more than I needed. Thank you, it really helped me understand my problem better and avoid mistakes in the future! Upvoted&accepted. :)